# Exception in thread main NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Tags: java, spring, heroku

during deploing my Spring Boot App on heroku i got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
```

My Pom.xml build part:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>

                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.5.11.3</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I only found some solutions for running application localy but i have this problem only on Heroku side. In other solutions it is solved by updating dependencies. Problem is i have no idea how can i deploy my dependencies to HerokuApp.

Answer (score 1):

This error is Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.
According to official source: [Check this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

Check if your application Spring boot class like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Can you publish your project tree ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for that late answer but i was busy.
So this is my main method which i want to run.

```
package com.wiktor.ecommerce;

import com.wiktor.ecommerce.Service.UserService;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class EcommerceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is my project tree:
[image: Project tree]